# Recover VM Instance when Google Cloud Console Free Trial expires

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I've done a search for my question and am surprised not to find an answer because it must be fairly common occurrence.

My google cloud console free trial expired about two months ago without me realising it.  I have now upgraded to a paid account, but my Wordpress VM instance is no longer present.  In fact there are no VM instances. The only option on Google's API interface is to create a new instance.

Does this mean that the VM instance has been permanently deleted and cannot be recovered?  If it can, I would appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think this link provides the required answer. We need to upgrade the gcloud account with 30 days of expiry.

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52798837/1761743 for detailed answer.

You can find more detail at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions#after-end).