# Site Down/Server costs 10x than it should/missing VM instance - Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, migrate

I have disabled billing on my google cloud platform for 1 month. I came back today and activated billing again to try to access my files and retrieve it.

I managed to activate Billing (of course, one click, no problem), but i didn't manage to access any of my files. Customer support didn't help at all... They just told they want me to upgrade my account to see my files. Ridiculous... My files are a hostage now?

I am so disapointed with google cloud as a Hosting solution.... I want to migrate away to Siteground and for that i need:

- MySQL database
- wp-content

Does anyone know how can I migrate away from google cloud platform if I'm missing my VM instance???

Please help, i'm desperate...

Comment: When you close your billing account, you are not paying for those resources. Google will then delete your resources. If the VM is deleted, your data stored on the VM is gone.

Comment: Google won't keep your data for free one month. Nothing in hostage, it's only standard.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Cloud virtual instances disappear after trial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797970/google-cloud-virtual-instances-disappear-after-trial)

Comment: horrible experience. I love google products, I really do. I expected much more from cloud.