# Is there any way to recover data after free trial on Google Cloud WITHOUT being charged?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, free, trial

I know that there is an extremely similar topic ([Recover VM Instance when Google Cloud Console Free Trial expires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52355999/recover-vm-instance-when-google-cloud-console-free-trial-expires)) but it doesnt answer my question. I wanted to ask if there is any way to download my files after the free trial without paying? The trial just expired a few hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

You have 30 days to solve this problem at which point Google can and often does delete your data. My recommendation is for you to solve the account problem (billing and payments) so that you can download your data. Unless you have a huge amount of data,  you are looking at pennies to download data. Then delete the project and billing account to prevent future charges.

The following links will help you enable your account and then once you have downloaded your data to delete the project and billing account.

[End of Free Trial](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#end)

[Create, modify, or close your self-serve Cloud Billing account](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account)

[Shutting down (deleting) projects](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_projects)